# Refresh Page after update php

Tags: php, javascript, refresh

i need a javascript to help me refresh my page after i update the data. i have coded out t
he update function all i need to refresh the page after the data is updated how do i do that.

This is what i have done so far

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","fbappsadmin","dbP@ssw0rd") or die(mysql_error()) ;
    mysql_select_db("jetstardatabase") or die(mysql_error()) ;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


    $options = array(
        '1' => 1,
        '2' => 2,
    );

    if (isset($_POST['list'])) {
        $value = (int)$_POST['list'];
    } else {
        $value = 0; // default value;

    }   
        $cmeter = $cmeter - $value;

        mysql_query("INSERT orders SET quantity='$value',fbId='$fbme',fbName='$fbName', email ='$fbEmail', dealName='$dealName'" );
        mysql_query("UPDATE stardeal SET cmeter='$cmeter'WHERE dealId='$dealId'");

 }

?>
```

Comment: Can you give us more details of the context ?

Comment: Seriously hope this code isn't actually for [JetStar](http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/home)!

Comment: @Treffynnon I hope so too, looks like he's even put the login details in!

Answer (score 1):

Just put this PHP at the end of your update logic, it **must** be before any HTML output;

```
header("Location: /mypage.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Web pages work like this:

```
page (client) -> request (made in url) (server) -> new page (client)
```

By sending a request to the server, the server generates the new page and serves it back to the browser. You have the middle part, you need the entry and exit pages.

Answer (score 0):

Like blake said, ajax or PHP would probably be prefered. Otherwise, to answer your question, you can use:
`document.location = window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

If you need javascript, then use this code:

```
<script>window.top.location='mypage.html'</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refresh your browser page using PHP. You have to use either META or Javascript.

Using Meta tag inside `<HEAD>` and `</HEAD>`:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">`

Using Javascript:

`location.reload(true)`

Comment: `You cannot refresh your browser page using PHP. You have to use either META or Javascript.` Yes you can. See my answer.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz `header()` in PHP will redirect the browser to the specified location. Once the page is loaded, you CANNOT redirect/refresh the page in PHP. In his question, he asked about HOW TO refresh a page, and that methods are either `META` or `location.reload()`. It all depends on "whether the page IS loaded", or "the page IS NOT loaded yet".

Comment: ..and there is no context to wether the page is loaded, so `header()` may be the correct way to do it, I'd hazard a guess it is because it's just under the mysql connection logic